# undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 3. There is a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857070/rspec-user-test-gives-undefined-local-variable-or-method-confirmed-at). But it did not solve my problem, neither did any other solution.

My migration is as follows

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t| 
      t.confirmable 
    end
    add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
  end
end
```

I do have `devise :confirmable` added in `User` model.

My `rake db:migrate` gives no output. and my sign up page gives the error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'confirmed_at' for #User
```

Anybody has a clue?

Comment: You should know that the migration helpers (like `t.confirmable`) in devise are deprecated as of version 2.0. From now on, you should be [adding devise columns manually](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok. I solved it. The migration is outdated. Generate new migration with same code but another name.

1.Run command:

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise_v1
```

2.In the migration file:

```
class AddConfirmableToDeviseV1 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t| 
      t.confirmable 
    end
    add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
  end
end
```

3.Then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 21):

As of the latest devise, you just need to remove comments from the following lines on the devise users migration..   (2013....._devise_create_users.rb)

```
  # Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

Answer (score 17):

Note for myself. Someone might find it helpful:
What we need is 2 commands below:

```
    rake db:migrate:reset 
    rake db:reset
```

Voila! It works!

Comment: What are `db:reset` and `rake db:migrate:reset`? `rake -D db:reset` or `rake -D db:migrate:reset` doesn't show anything...

Answer (score 17):

To tie in @DevDude's answer with the accepted answer - if you already have an existing `Users` model to which you need to add confirmable, the full migration code for the version of Devise current as of 4/14 is:

```
class AddConfirmableToDeviseV1 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
       # Confirmable
       t.string   :confirmation_token
       t.datetime :confirmed_at
       t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
       t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
     end
     add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. In fact, when you initially generate a devise migration, this will be commented out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Mongoid and got this same error. I added these fields and got rspec to go green on my 16 examples.

```
field :confirmation_token,   :type => String
field :confirmed_at,         :type => Time
field :confirmation_sent_at, :type => Time
field :unconfirmed_email,    :type => String
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding confirmable to your user model. The devise gem needs your application to have the confirmation_token, confirmed_at, confirmed_sent_at, unconfirmed_email and confirmation_token in the user table.

1. Generate a new migration using the command below

   rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
2. Add the code to the newly created migration file

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    User.update_all confirmed_at: DateTime.now
end
def down
    remove_index :users, :confirmation_token
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
  end
end
```

3. Run the migrations

   rails db:migrate

Comment: This is the current solution as of 2023.