# How to fix the Internal 500 Error in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting this error when I try to run my application. It states that there is an undefined method error in the application, but doesn't state where. The closest error I could find as tangible was this:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x6049800>):
```

I'm not sure which part this is directing to. Could someone please tell me what this error means?

This is the code for the devise_users file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
   create_table(:users) do |t|
    ## Database authenticatable
    t.string :name,               null: false, default: ""
    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
    t.string :about
    t.string :avatar
    t.string :cover

    ## Recoverable
    t.string   :reset_password_token
    t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

    ## Rememberable
    t.datetime :remember_created_at

    ## Trackable
    t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
    t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
    t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
    t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
    t.string   :confirmation_token
    t.datetime :confirmed_at
    t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    t.timestamps null: false
    ## Confirmable
    # t.string   :confirmation_token
    # t.datetime :confirmed_at
    # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

    ## Lockable
    # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock  strategy is :failed_attempts
    # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
    # t.datetime :locked_at


    t.timestamps null: false
  end

  add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
  add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
  # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
  add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
 end
 end
```

There are not any other places within the application where the method is called, therefore the error states that the method is being called somewhere when it isn't. How can I fix this error?

Comment: try to find `confirmed_at` in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

Your migration file `DeviseCreateUsers` created a table `users` in the database, and one of the columns in that table is `confirmed_at`.

In your `app/models/user.rb` file you probably declared your devise configuration like:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :registerable, :confirmable

  ...
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base`, the class `User` is inheriting from, automatically creates "getter" and "setter" methods for database columns (i.e. `confirmed_at`), so the method `#confirmed_at` should already be defined.

So if the method is "missing", you may not have run the database migrations (e.g. `rake db:migrate`)

Comment: Similarly, you could try to [regenerate the migration file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108621/3345375) and/or [re-run the migration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13475181/3345375).

Comment: The program won't let me migrate the file. It states that there is a not a method defined called confirmable in the regenerated migration file. Also, how would I use t.confirmable properly in the application?

Comment: It is correct about the undefined `t.confirmable`. `t.confirmable` would not be used in the migration file itself, `devise :confirmable` would go in your user model. Your migration file simply needs the following: `t.string :confirmation_token`, `t.datetime :confirmed_at`, and `t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at`

Comment: This is exactly what I have. Only this time, it states that there is an ArgumentError in Devise::Registrations#Create

Comment: Are you still getting the `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'confirmed_at' for #<User:0x6049800>):` error?

Comment: No, that's fixed. Right now this is a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for `confirmed_at` -- it seems you used it somewhere without defining it first.

It would be nice if the error message gave you a file name and a line number, but (depending on which text editor or IDE you're using) you might be able to run a search on the entire Rails app at once.

My guess is you called the `confirmed_at` method on a user object (`user_1.confirmed_at`, for example) and the method wasn't defined in `class User`.

Comment: I have found the confirmed_at method, but it is only mentioned at the part where the method is declared. Also, there are no other uses of 'confirmed_at' in the application. How would this create an error?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe there's an issue with the syntax and it messes up the method definition? (Like an extra or missing `end` keyword.)

Comment: Please post your code (in context) and let's take a look at it.